# Meteor loops and conditional data

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteorite, meteor-helper

Given a years worth of months and data that returned may only apply to specific months, how can I render this in blaze please, but also render 0's where an applicable record does not exist?

What I'm working with:

```
{{#each month in months}}
  {{#each recordDataset }}
    {#if equals recordDataset.period month}<td>{{ recordDataset.value}}</td>{/if}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

This nested loop obviously returns too many  because it is looping through 2 separate sets of data. I can think how to do this in other languages of course but not in blaze.

For example, what would be ideal would be:

```
{{#each month in months}}
  {{#if recordSet['month'] == month}}
    <td>{{ recordDataset.value}}</td>
  {{else}}
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

But I don't see how I can achieve this.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: try to move all of the logic to JS

Comment: Can you add some more code about the recordDataset. I can help/suggest you but I didn't get what you need exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code example, `recordDataSet` has a property `month` which you'd like to compare to each `month` in `months`.  Given that, you can just create an equals operator and use that for comparison:

```
Template.registerHelper( 'equals', ( v1, v2 ) => {
  return v1 === v2;
});

{{#each month in months}}
  {{#if equals recordDataSet.month month}}
    <td>{{recordDataset.month}}</td>
  {{else}}
    <td>0</td>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Since I don't have the schema of your recordDataSet, you'll have to adjust according to your needs.